# Overlay average of data in Plotly plot inside a Streamlit app

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

In this simplified `streamlit` app, I am using `plotly, to plot some dummy data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st

n = 100
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.arange(n), "y": np.random.randn(n), "file": ["f1"] * n})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.arange(n), "y": np.random.randn(n), "file": ["f2"] * n})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", color="file")
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

The app looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to overlay two horizontal lines inside this plot that represent the average of the data in the selected x-range. That means that this average would have to be recomputed on every zoom event. Additionally, I want to write that average using `st.write(...)`.
I am not sure how to add a callback (which I assume is necessary) in the `streamlit` context.
Is there a simple way to achieve an interactive computation of the chart's data based on zoom events?

Comment: according to [this comment](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/callback-data-from-plotly-charts/34362), it appears that callbacks from plotly charts in streamlit haven't yet been implemented, but you might be able to use [this library](https://github.com/yihui-he/streamlit-plotly-events)